# How to iterate a class that overload the operator[]?

Tags: c++

I have a class like this:

```
class C {
private:
    std::unordered_map<char, int> m = {{'a', 1}, {'b', 2}, {'c', 3}};

public:
    int operator[](const char& key) const {
        return m.find(key)->second;
    }
};
```

Is it possible to iterate the elements of the map without modifying the class?

I want to have something like:

```
for (auto x: c) {
    // x -> a map element
}
```

Comment: You have to provide `begin(c)` and `end(c)`. Seems hard without modifying the class.

Comment: Almost, but no. There is no way to retrieve the iterators of `m`, nor a list of its keys, so you can't implement the `begin`/`end` pair.

Comment: Looks like I need to either modify the class, or somehow find the keys, right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, a [ranged-for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) loop does not use `operator[]`

The definition of

```
for ( range_declaration : range_expression ) loop_statement
```

Is that it is treated as-if it were (without introducing `__names`)

```
{
    auto && __range = range_expression ; 
    auto __begin = begin_expr ;
    auto __end = end_expr ;
    for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin) {   
        range_declaration = *__begin; 
        loop_statement    
    } 
}
```

With the following rules for `begin_expr` and `end_expr`:

> - If `range_expression` is an expression of array type, then `begin_expr` is `__range` and `end_expr` is `(__range + __bound)`,
>     where `__bound` is the number of elements in the array (if the array
>     has unknown size or is of an incomplete type, the program is
>     ill-formed)
> - If range_expression is an expression of a class type `C` that has both a member named `begin` and a member named `end` (regardless of
>     the type or accessibility of such member), then `begin_expr` is
>     `__range.begin()` and `end_expr` is `__range.end()`;
> - Otherwise, `begin_expr` is `begin(__range)` and `end_expr` is `end(__range)`, which are found via argument-dependent lookup (non-ADL
>     lookup is not performed).

A simple change to your class which would suffice would to be add `begin` and `end`, delegating to `m.begin()` and `m.end()`

```
class C {
private:
    std::unordered_map<char, int> m = {{'a', 1}, {'b', 2}, {'c', 3}};

public:
    int operator[](const char& key) const {
        return m.find(key)->second; 
        // return m.at(key); or return m[key]; are both safer than this
    }
    std::unordered_map<char, int>::iterator begin() {
        return m.begin();
    }
    // overloaded on the constness of "this"
    std::unordered_map<char, int>::const_iterator begin() const {
        return m.begin();
    }
    std::unordered_map<char, int>::iterator end() {
        return m.end();
    }   
    // overloaded on the constness of "this"
    std::unordered_map<char, int>::const_iterator end() const {
        return m.end();
    }   
};
```

Comment: `const` version with `const_iterator` might be good too.

Comment: And depending on how the class is used, it might make sense to only provide const iterators in order to encapsulate changes to the map.

Comment: Adding `noexcept` might be better.

Comment: `cbegin`/`cend`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit not used by `for (:)`

Comment: @Caleth But you don't design an interface just for one language construct

Answer (score 4):

No.

In addition to the constraints imposed specifically by ranged-for, which others have covered, your class does not expose any way to know which elements are in the map, not even the first or last element keys. It does not expose any iterators. It simply does not expose sufficient information to perform iteration.

Answer (score 2):

A class can be iterated if it provides iterators i.e. if `begin(c)` and `end(c)` return iterators (or `c.begin()` and `c.end()`). Your class doesn't provide iterators, and it won't be possible to implement the iterators outside of the class, since the internal map is private.

So, the answer is no, the class does need to be modified.